# Where do I put the CiaoCiao figurine?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening-2019

I have been looking all around the village but I can't seem to find anywhere to put the CiaoCiao figurine I got from the Trendy Game. What do I do with this figurine? Where can I place it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [guide](https://www.vg247.com/2019/09/25/zelda-links-awakening-figurines-guide-figure/) will show you where each one goes. Specifically for the CiaoCiao figurine:

> Its pedestal is on the table in Madam MeowMeow’s house, appropriately.